# What alternative backends does sudo support and how is it configured?

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

When preparing for the Red Hat Certified Engineer certification examination, I came across this quote in my study notes about the `sudo` command.

> By default, the policy is maintained as a flat text file, /etc/sudoers(although other, possibly remote, backend databases are also supported).

I have never heard of this piece of information until recently and a quick Google search does not turn up anything useful with regards to this.

Is this particular quote accurate? If so, how do I make the appropriate changes to configure `sudo` to use an alternative(presumably centralized) database for its policies?

Answer (score 2):

[`sudo` supports LDAP natively](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.7/sudoers.ldap.man.html) as a replacement for `/etc/sudoers`.  It also has [an API for third-party plugins](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.7/sudo_plugin.man.html), one of which (for Quest One) is [listed on `sudo`'s website](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/plugins.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sudo can be configured to use [LDAP](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.7/sudoers.ldap.man.html), which allows for distributed network based sudo configuration. The linked man page on the sudo website is quite detailed on the subject.